# Error in creating thumbnails from my form

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a problem with a script of  mine to create some thumbnails from images/photos that users can upload from my form in my personal website.

First of  all, after all the possible controls to prevent any possible attacks, I rename the photo uploaded from a user using some PHP functions, and then I'd like to show my logged user (and for the logging function I use here the sessions)  his previously uploaded images/photos as thumbnails, giving then him the possibility to click on them and to obtain this way the photos with their original dimensions.

The problem I got is with ***the thumbnails***, that I'm not able to create!!!.

I created a new table in my MySql database this way:

```
CREATE TABLE uploaded
    (id_file INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
     url_file VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     name_file VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     type_file VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     description VARCHAR(255),
     notes TEXT,
     data_insert DATETIME NOT NULL,
     address_IP CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
     username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
     id_user INT(11) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(id_file)
    );
```

Then I created a file in PHP called **vision.php** to show the user his images, and this file parses itself another file in the query string this way:

```
echo '<img src="thumb.php?id_file=' . $row['id_file'] . '" alt="' . $row['id_file'] . '" /> 
<br /><br /><br />';
```

The directory that contains the photos called **“uploaded”**  is set with the permissions in 777. I gave in fact in a shell (I'm using  a GNU/Linux distro) on my local server Apache this:

sudo chmod 777 uploaded

and I see there the photos I myself uploded on my localhost, where I always test the websites I create.

Anyway online I got the same problem.

Here is the source of the file I called **vision.php**:

```
 <?php
    try
        {   
            // Report all PHP errors
            error_reporting(-1);            
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM uploaded WHERE id_user = ? ORDER BY id_file");
            $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['id_user']));

            if ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
                {   
                    // Here I use a do/while looop
                    do
                        {
                            echo '<br /><br />Your images:' . '&nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="upload.php">Go back</a><br /><br />';                                 
                            echo '<img src="thumb.php?id_file=' . $row['id_file'] . '" alt="' . $row['id_file'] . '" /> 
<br /><br /><br />'; 
                        } 
                    while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) );                
                }
            else
                {
                    echo '<br /><br /> <div class="centra">Hi, ' . $_SESSION['username'] . ', you sent me no images up to now.
<br /><br /> <a href="upload.php">Send me an image/photo, if you wish</a></div>';

                    include 'footer.php';
                    exit;
                }

        } // end try {}
    catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
            die;        
        }   
?>
```

and this is the script I called **thumb.php**:

```
<?php
     // I wanna have a jpeg image as thumbnail
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 

    // go on with the session
    session_start();

    require_once 'config_db.php';

    try {
        //chmod("./uploaded/", 0777);

        // Report all PHP errors
        error_reporting(-1);

        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM uploaded WHERE id_file = ? ORDER BY id_file");
        // the parameter contained in the querystring in vision.php
        $stmt->execute(array($_GET['id_file']));
        $row = stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);       
        switch ($row['tipo_file']) {
            case 'png':                 
            $image = imagecreatefrompng('uploaded/' . $row['nome_file'] . '.' . $row['tipo_file']);
            break;  

            case 'jpg' || 'jpeg': 
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg('uploaded/' . $row['nome_file'] . '.' . $row['tipo_file']);
            break;

            case 'gif':
            $image = imagecreatefromgif('uploaded/' . $row['nome_file'] . '.' . $row['tipo_file']);
            break;  

            default:            
            die('Impossible to get the image extension');       }               

        $width = imagesx($image);
        $height = imagesy($image); 
        $thumbsize = 250;
        $perc = min($thumbsize / $width, $thumbsize / $height);
        $thumb_width = intval($perc * $width);
        $thumb_height = intval($perc * $height);                
        // The thumbnail 
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height); 

        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width, $height);
        imagejpeg($thumb, NULL, 80);                
        // destroy the thumbnail to free some memory from the server
        imagedestroy($thumb); 

    } // end try {}
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
        die;        
    }   
?>
```

I'd like to add here some errors I can see from the error_file contained in the directory /opt/lampp/logs:

I investigated this error_file contained in the directory /opt/lampp/logs and here I found this:

```
[Wed Jun 26 19:37:34.279824 2013] [:error] [pid 2933] [client 127.0.0.1:43215] PHP Warning:  **imagecreatefromjpeg(uploaded/046ccd6f930959786f71447f2ecf228d814481eb40481889d9ea619191a153cb12f585bbae867a66.jpeg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/new_site_local/thumb.php on line 35, referer:[http://localhost/new_site_local/vision.php]**
[Wed Jun 26 19:37:34.279915 2013] [:error] [pid 2933] [client 127.0.0.1:43215] PHP Warning:  imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/new_site_local/thumb.php on line 47, referer:[    http://localhost/new_site_local/vision.php]
[Wed Jun 26 19:37:34.279938 2013] [:error] [pid 2933] [client 127.0.0.1:43215] PHP Warning:  imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/new_site_local/thumb.php on line 48, referer: [http://localhost/new_site_local/vision.php]
[Wed Jun 26 19:37:34.279961 2013] [:error] [pid 2933] [client 127.0.0.1:43215] PHP Warning:  Division by zero in /opt/lampp/htdocs/new_site_local/thumb.php on line 59, referer:[http://localhost/new_site_local/vision.php]
```

etc.

Thanks all!

Comment: Please elaborate specifically on the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

### The first error is the the most important

"failed to open stream: No such file or directory" means that your code couldn't find the file. Possibly because the file's relative path does not get expanded as you expected it to.

Try using `var_dump(realpath($filename))` like this:

```
case 'jpg' || 'jpeg': 
    $filename = 'uploaded/' . $row['nome_file'] . '.' . $row['tipo_file'];
    var_dump(
         file_exists($filename),
         realpath($filename),
         is_readable($filename)
    );
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    break;
```

You'll likely notice that `file_exists`, `realpath`, `is_readable` yield `boolean(false)`.

### For testing and error reporting and displaying

Try separating the actual thumbnail generation code from the database read code. Hard code a file name and see if the thumbnail generation actually works for that file name.

Also try using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);` to be able to read any errors PHP might be sending.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I already use the two functions you mentioned, as you can see in my scripts where I write error_reporting(-1); that's the same as error_reportin(E_ALL). Then I tried ('display_errors', TRUE); but I see nothing.

Comment: I tried your code, and I thought too, it showed me the error, but I obtain nothing in vision.php. I just see in the error_log file the same error, that's: [Sun Jul 07 18:45:10.878066 2013] [:error] [pid 2667] [client 127.0.0.1:56751] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg(uploaded/046ccd6f930959786f71447f2ecf228d814481eb40481889d9ea619191a153cb12f585bbae867a66.jpeg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/new_site_local/thumb.php on line 44, referer: [http://localhost/new_site_local/vision.php]. I don't really know what I can do to solve this problem. Bye